# how to fix error after refreshing the userpage in React?

Tags: reactjs, object, error-handling, react-redux

can someone help me to understand the after i login and in user page i try to refresh page it throw an error ?

the error is :

**Error: Objects are not valid as a React child (found: object with keys {}). If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead.**

here is my code
https://codesandbox.io/s/affectionate-swanson-h548n

Comment: We can't recreate the error from your Codesandbox because we'd need a user's log-in information. Please post a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/s/happy-babycat-f3e60

Answer (score 1):

The above error occurs when an object is passed as react child.

`const user = useSelector(selectUser);`

After reload, the returned value from useSelector in Dashboard.js is `"{}"`.

Add a check like `!_.isEmpty(user)` before passing the user variable to the returned JSX.

Comment: it's Lodash? i can't understand why i should use it,and where

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).